# adding methods in java (jGrasp)

Tags: methods

In my java assignment I created a program that executed what was supposed to happen, but my feedback from my professor was: The main task for this program was for you to learn to create methods; however, you did not create any methods in your program.  How do I add methods to this?

```
/* Daniel Martos
   This program will make use of methods with parameters and return values, 
   the scanner class, string methods, and nested for Loops.  It will ask the
   user for their full name and the number of credits that they are taking.
   It will then calculate the cost of their tuition and print out the user's
   full name, and tuition cost.
*/

// Import the java.util package in order to work with the scanner class.
import java.util.*;

public class Martos3 {
// Create constants.
   public static final double PER_CREDIT = 302.00;

   public static void main (String [] args)  {
// Create variables and objects.
   int credTaken; 
   double cost;
   String fullName;

// Create the console object to allow us to read information in from the    keyboard.   
   Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

// Create executable code.   
   System.out.println ("Welcome to the Cal U Tuition Calculator Program");

   System.out.print ("Please enter your full name: ");
   fullName = console.nextLine ();

   System.out.print ("Please enter the number of credits taken: ");
   credTaken = console.nextInt ();

// Add a Nested for Loop to add the dashes
   for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)  {
      for (int j = 1; j <= 50; j++)   {
         System.out.print ("-");
      }
      System.out.println ();
  }

// Calculate the tuition cost.
   cost = (credTaken * PER_CREDIT);

// Print out "Tuition calucation for" and the user's full name followed by a .
   System.out.println ("Tuition calulation for " + fullName + ".");
// Print out "Credits Taken =" with the number of credits that the user enters.   
   System.out.println ("Credits Taken = " + credTaken);
// Print out "Tuition Cost = $" and the cost of tutition calculation. 
   System.out.println ("Tuition Cost = $" + cost);

   }
}
```

Comment: do you tried to get the information , exactly what is a method?

Comment: The first method should be used to ask the student's name, the second should be to ask how many credits the student is taking, and the third should be to calculate the tuition cost.  I've emailed my professor (preferred way to contact) and posted to my class discussion board and I've received no feeback.  I'm desperate, because it is due tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below piece of code, Modified your code

`displayResults` is a method which is used to display the results.`calculateFees` is the other method used for calculation. Now the rest part depends upon you i.e. how your requirement is? I have given you the sample code in this way you can implement other things.

```
// Create constants.
public static final double PER_CREDIT = 302.00;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Create variables and objects.
    int credTaken;
    String fullName;

    // Create the console object to allow us to read information in from the
    // keyboard.
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Create executable code.
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Cal U Tuition Calculator Program");

    System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");
    fullName = console.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of credits taken: ");
    credTaken = console.nextInt();
    displayResults(credTaken,fullName);

}

static void displayResults(int credTaken, String fullName) {
    // Add a Nested for Loop to add the dashes
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 50; j++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    double cost = calculateFees(credTaken);
    // Print out "Tuition calucation for" and the user's full name followed
    // by a .
    System.out.println("Tuition calulation for " + fullName + ".");
    // Print out "Credits Taken =" with the number of credits that the user
    // enters.
    System.out.println("Credits Taken = " + credTaken);
    // Print out "Tuition Cost = $" and the cost of tutition calculation.
    System.out.println("Tuition Cost = $" + cost);

}

static double calculateFees(int credTaken) {
    // Calculate the tuition cost.
    return (credTaken * PER_CREDIT);
}
```

Comment: Thank-you so much....I hope I can use this as a good reference for my current assignment.